# Understanding memory mapping conceptually

Tags: memory-management, virtual-memory, memory-access

I've already read several blogs and questions on stack exchange, but I'm unable to grasp what the real drawbacks of memory mapped files are. I see the following are frequently listed:

1. You can't memory map large files (>4GB) with a 32-bit address space.

QUESTION #1:
Why? Isn't that the whole point of virtual memory? If a file is greater than 4GB, it may cause trashing by swapping out some memory mapped pages, but why is there a limitation?

2. If the application is trying to read from a part of the file that is not loaded in the page cache, it (the application) will incur a penalty in the form of a page-fault, which in turn means increased I/O latency for the operation.

QUESTION #2:
Isn't this the case for a standard file I/O operation as well? If an application tries to read from a part of a file that is not yet cached, it will result in a syscall that will cause the kernel to load the relevant page/block from the device. And on top of that, the page needs to be copied back to the user-space buffer.

Is the concern here that page-faults are somehow more expensive than syscalls in general - my interpretation of what [Linus Torvalds says here](https://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=95496636207616&w=2)? Is it because page-faults are blocking => the thread is not scheduled off the CPU => we are wasting precious time? Or is there something I'm missing here?

3. Overhead of kernel mappings and data structures - [according to Linus Torvalds](https://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=95496636207616&w=2). I won't even attempt to question this premise, because I don't know much about the internals of Linux kernel. :)
4. No support for async I/O for memory mapped files.

QUESTION #3:
Is there an architectural limitation with supporting async I/O for memory mapped files, or is it just that it no one got around to doing it?

5. One drawback that I thought of was that if too many files are memory mapped, this can cause lower available system resources (memory) => can cause pages to be evicted => potentially more page faults. So some prudence is required in deciding what files to memory map and their access patterns.

QUESTION #4:
Vaguely related, but my interpretation of [this article](https://manybutfinite.com/post/page-cache-the-affair-between-memory-and-files/) is that the kernel can read-ahead for standard I/O (even without fadvise()) but does not read-ahead for memory mapped files (unless issued an advisory with madvice()). Is this accurate? If this statement is in-fact true, is that why syscalls for standard I/O maybe faster, as opposed to a memory mapped file which will almost always cause a page-fault?

Comment: Q1: because with 32-bits you can address only $2^{32}$ blocks. And each block is a single byte in case of memory mapping.

Comment: Thank you for the comment Dmitri. Now that I think about it a bit more, it makes sense for 32-bit address spaces.

Answer (score 1):

With memory-mapped files, a file is mapped to a pointer p, and byte #i of the file can be accessed through the pointer p+i. For each byte in the file, there must be an address available in the logical address space. With 32 bit, there are only 2^32 possible logical addresses, so 2^32 bytes in a memory mapped file that can be accessed at all.

You are confusing address space and RAM. A 64 bit computer with just 1 GB if RAM can memory map multi-terabyte files without problems. There will be lots of paging, but it will work. With a 32 bit computer, no chance.

Answer (score 0):

Re #1: If your address space is 32 bits, you can address only 4GiB by pointers into memory. You can process larger files by e.g. reading the sequentially, or `lseek(2)` into it (note that usually `off_t` is a 64-bit type today).

Re #2: Yes, the operating system will read (part of) the file into memory for munging it. The offset into the on-disk file doesn't have to be limited to 32 bits. For quite some time now Unix/Linux handles "large files" with 64 bit file offsets, lately by default (in the beginning some incantation was needed to enable that).